Enigmatic Puzzle 5: Reflections
Particularly looking for feedback on this new enigmatic puzzle. I like the concept of it, but have gotten some comments that it might be too difficult without any hints. Let me know what you think. Happy to share hints as needed.

Reflections 
Each time I saw it, I took one more look. 
VMRTNZ 
OAXSSNW 
TOEXPGLI


V znantrq gb trg guerr jbeqf juvpu jura gur ortvaavat yrggref ner ernq qbjajneqf vg fcryyf ‘rng’ V nz abg fher vs guvf vf gur vagraqrq fbyhgvba!

@PDT That's not quite the answer in this case. Feel free to share more of your progress with me and I can let you know if you're on the right track!

Ok sure! Will do

Fb sne V tbg hfvat gur ngonfu pvcure ba gur gbc jbeq ‘ravtzn’. Gura V hfrq gur ivtrarer pvcure ba gur obggbz gjb jbeqf hfvat gur xrl ‘Barybjre’ gb trg ‘naguref’ naq ‘pnegrfcr’ sebz urer gur ynfg jbeq pna or znqr vagb genpr CFR ernqvat onpxjneqf, V nz abg fher ubj gb cebterff sebz urer

@PDT Ab jbeevrf, urer'f jung V pna bssre. Ybbxf yvxr gur svefg jbeq vf n tbbq fgneg, lbh erpbtavmrq jung jnf zrnag ol ersyrpgvba. Ubjrire, gurer'f abguvat va gur chmmyr gb vaqvpngr zhygvcyr qvssrerag pvcuref orvat hfrq, fb V'q fgvpx jvgu gur ersyrpgvba vqrn.

V bofreir gung rnpu yvar unf bar zber yrggre guna gur yvar nobir. V vasre, gura, gung gurer ner gjb 'vg'f va gur svefg gjb yvarf, naq gurer znl or n guveq. Vf guvf ba gur evtug genpx?

Hasbeghangryl gur ahzore bs yrggref va rnpu yvar orvat 6, 7, 8 vf whfg n pbvapvqrapr.

Hm. I don't think we've got a lot to go with here, but we have two hints, "reflection" and "one more look". My take on this: rot13(Gurer ner guerr qvssrerag xvaqf bs ersyrpgvba. Gur svefg jbeq hfrf gur svefg bar; gur frbaqf bar hfrf gur svefg naq frpbaq naq gur ynfg bar hfrf nyy guerr, fb rnpu gnxrf "bar zber ybbx". Nccylvat gur Ngonfu pvcure frireny gvzrf whfg qrpbqrf ntnva, fb vg zhfg or fbzguvat ryfr. Vs vg vf erirefvat gur jbeq, vg zhfg or gur guveq ersyrpgvba. )

rot13(Ohg gurer ner fb znal cbffvoyr jnlf: Gur svefg jbeq zvtug or hfrq gb znxr n xrlrq nycunorg; gur ersyrpgvba zvtug or ba gur ebjf bs gur xrlobneq be ba tencuvpny ercrfragngvbaf bs gur yrggref (Zbefr, Oenvyyr, Frzncuber)). I guess I'm missing something obvious here. I have to reflect on this some more ...

@MOehm Lbh zvtug or bireguvaxvat vg n ovg. V'z abg fher vs lbh jnag n uvag lrg nf lbh'ir vaqvpngrq lbh jnag gb qb fbzr zber ersyrpgvba, ohg ernpu bhg vs lbh'q yvxr bar!

Thanks, but I'm fine at the moment. My comments were more in the line of general feedback. By the way: I hadn't seen what PDT found out about the first word. My first thoughts were about the symmetry of the letters themselves.

Could we have a hint perhaps?

@PDT Fbeel, whfg frrvat guvf erdhrfg abj. Nzbm znantrq gb fbyir vg orybj, ohg gur uvag V'q tvir vf va gur gntyvar: frrvat n yrggre ntnva znqr vg trg pbqrq qvssreragyl.

The answer to this puzzle is:

 Arthur Scherbius

Reasoning:
Both the word "Reflections" and the nature of the letters suggest the use of

 The Atbash cipher (this was also noted by PDT in comments).


 Running the full text through the cipher yields:
ENIGMA
LZCHHMD
GLVCKTOR
 Line 1 looks promising, but what to make of the next two lines?

Looking more closely, it becomes apparent that lines 2 and 3 are

 suspiciously close to "MACHINE INVENTOR", with only a few letters off by a rotation of 1 to 3. The amounts to rotate the letters are:
 1100111
 22023000
 But what could be the source of this (non) pattern?

Looking back to the puzzle, it states:

 Each time I saw it, I took one more look.

So let's try that:

 The first char of line 2, decoded, is "L". We've already seen one 'L' in the original text:
VMRTNZ
OAXSSNW
TOEXPGLI
 Therefore, we rotate it up one char, and it becomes 'M'.
 Similar for the second char, 'Z'.
 The third char of line 2, decoded, is "C". Up to now, we haven't seen a 'C'. As I "haven't seen it", there is no need to rotate it, so it stays "C".
 This continues in a similar fashion. For example, the first char of line 3 is "G". There was a 'G' in the original cipher, and we also saw it a second time in the first decoding (part of "enigma"). So this gets rotated up two steps, to "I".

But wait, that doesn't quite work!

 When we get to 'D' in line 2, this fails, as we need to rotate it 1 but D hasn't appeared. So let's tweak this to a new algorithm:


 Assume the user had a message to encrypt using Atbash, but each time they encrypted a letter they'd seen already in the plain text, they then rotated it up the # of times they'd seen it in the original plain text.
 This means "ENIGMA" is rot-0 after Atbash.
 'MA' is rotated up 1 after Atbash, as M and A have already appeared in the plain text "ENIGMA". So 'NZ' becomes 'OA'
 'CH' is rot-0 after Atbash.
 'I' is rotated up 1 after Atbash, as I appeared earlier in "ENIGMA MACH", so 'R' becomes 'S'.
 And so on.
 Continuing, we I believe we get "ENIGMA MACHINE INVENTOR" as the original plain text, which has been encoded with Atbash with the additional rotation amounts already guessed above.
 Here is a clearer picture of the shifts thanks to @codewarrior0 for helping tweak this:
ENIGMA MACHINE INVENTOR
000000 1100111 22023000

So, the final answer to the puzzle is

the inventor of the Enigma Machine:   Arthur Scherbius

Final comments:

 Without knowing the plain text in advance, I have no idea how you are supposed to reverse engineer this short of guessing the plain text? Unless I am misunderstanding something, I propose you change the algorithm to fit my "first attempt", which is reversible. On the other hand, this is tagged enigmatic and it is solvable, so maybe it is just fine as a puzzle (just don't use it as a real world cipher).


rot13(Jevgr gur guerr svany jbeqf, naq gura orarngu rnpu yrggre jevgr gur ahzore bs gvzrf lbh unir frra gung yrggre fb sne. Vs vg vf gur svefg bppheerapr, jevgr n mreb)

@codewarrior0 I think we're close - but "LZ", L appears twice but Z only once, but they both need rot-1, no?

Just pay attention to the final three words. It feels like working backwards and makes me want to say "not a cipher".

@codewarrior0 I had only spot checked this since it seemed so logical, but now I'm stuck. I can't account at all for why the 'D' got rotated to 'E', but 'TOR' did not, etc.

I will respond with an answer because I cannot use spoilered code blocks in a comment.

Actually no, even with the code blocks I'm just saying the same thing you already did. I'm not sure how to convey this. Just look at the final three words and ignore the rest of the puzzle. You can't deduce the rotation amounts from anything other than the final three words by themselves. It feels like working backwards.

@codewarrior0 Yeah I'd noted that seemed possible (though didn't check every letter) but it doesn't make any sense as an actual solution. I'll think about if I can phrase that in a way that seems justifiable.

Gunaxf sbe gnxvat hc guvf punyyratr. V nccerpvngr gur srrqonpx nobhg erirefr ratvarrevat, naq jnf onfvpnyyl ubcvat gung va gur frpbaq yvar, gur fbyire jbhyq erpbtavmr gung vg jnfa'g fgenvtug ngonfu. Sebz gurer, gura, rnpu yrggre va gur frpbaq yvar pbhyq pbzr sebz bar bs gjb yrggref va gur bevtvany zrffntr (sbe vafgnapr, Z zvtug unir pbzr sebz A be Z). Unccl gb punatr nebhaq gvgyr & gntyvar, ohg V yvxr univat guvf vqrn nf gur prageny gurzr.
Terng fbyir!

Partial answer/attempt to correct Amoz's answer:

Amoz inferred that the plaintext is "ENIGMA MACHINE INVENTOR". Print this phrase, and below it print the number of times each letter in the phrase had previously been seen only within this phrase. If it is the first time the letter occurs, print a zero. The result fits the shift amounts that Amoz found in an earlier step.
ENIGMA MACHINE INVENTOR
000000 1100111 22023000


Thanks! I'd finally got that while you wrote this up.

@Amoz Part of me is still screaming "This isn't a cipher! It's a one-way function!" and another part is saying "The word 'seen' is being incredibly misleading here. It's only acting on the letters that the 'encipherer' had seen going in as he was 'enciphering' the words."

@codewarrior0 You're absolutely right. I was thinking that seen was actually giving you that reference point of the encipherer, but let me know if you have suggestions for clarifying that language.
